# jquerymobile how to correctly refresh a radio button?

Tags: jquery-mobile, radio-button

I changed the label of a radio button in javascript and called the refresh function. But it never gets correctly refreshed. http://jsfiddle.net/V3qb9/69/

```
$("#radio-choice-d").siblings("label").text("Good");
//$("input[type='radio']:first").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
$('input:[name=radio-choice-b]:radio:checked').checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/V7qQt/ - you have to use domready, e.g. wait until everything is initalized, e.g. put everything in `$(function() { });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, should be

```
$("label[for='radio-choice-d'] span.ui-btn-text").text('new text');
```

Comment: No it should not, this is implementation defined